# How to handle connectivity loss properly in spotify android sdk?

Tags: android, performance, networking, android-mediaplayer, spotify

Am developing an Android application which should work mainly as a music player with several sources ,Spotify,SoundCloud and external storage.
on the normal state would receive information from the backend and then determine whether to play the song on spotify or soundcloud ,if for some reason the internet went off which is something is very probable for my customers the app should start playing from the device memory and yet as much as possible without interruption for the current song.

First i tried using a Broadcast Receiver to monitor the network state but since i found that android OS triggers the event multiple times with on and off thus I could not rely on it because of my application requirement and found that `SocketIO` connect event is way more stable.

Now i need two things:

1. Simulate network instability for mobile data on a real phone since the app is going to be working on mobile data mainly not WiFi.
2. Spotify SDK handles the connectivity loss by pausing wherever it buffered and keeps trying to load until the connection comes back, it just keep invoking `onTemporaryError()` with no parameters and no other playback error method gets invoked. Is there any way i can make it behave like android `MediaPlayer` ? it will invoke `onCompletation()` after it reaches where it buffered.

**UPDATE:** as for #1 i need the mobile data to go off and on randomly ,is that possible to be automated?